# No JS label.removeClass(); fara o que eu quero?

Tags: javascript

Js é  um grande aliado, mas para quem sabe melhor utilizá-lo,  estou com grandes dificuldade em um sistema simples que é uma validação de cpf, eu gostaria que ao ser valido o js removesse a label com a classe invalido e ao ser invalido ele removesse a label com a classe valido.

Include JS Já Incluso.

jS Code:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    // ## EXEMPLO 1
    // Aciona a validação a cada tecla pressionada
    var temporizador = false;
    $('.cpf_cnpj').keypress(function(){

        // O input que estamos utilizando
        var input = $(this);

        // Limpa o timeout antigo
        if ( temporizador ) {
            clearTimeout( temporizador );
        }

        // Cria um timeout novo de 500ms
        temporizador = setTimeout(function(){
            // Remove as classes de válido e inválido
            label.removeClass('valido');
            label.removeClass('invalido');

            // O CPF ou CNPJ
            var cpf_cnpj = input.val();

            // Valida
            var valida = valida_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj );

            // Testa a validação
            if ( valida ) {
                label.addClass('valido');
            } else {
               label.addClass('invalido');
            }
        }, 500);

    });
});
 </script>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<label for="Cpf" class="valido" style="display:none">Valido</label>
<label for="Cpf" class="invalido" style="display:none">Invalido</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele fará, mas não porque você está confundindo o identificador `label` com os elementos `label` no HTML. Nesse caso você teria que usar os métodos do DOM para obter todos os elementos `label` para depois modificar-los. Há mais métodos do que esses, mas são úteis:

- `document.getElementsByTagName`. Retorna todos elementos com o nome da tag especificado no primeiro parâmetro, dentro de uma array. Se tiver um container, indexe `getElementsByTagName` nele. `Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName`
- `document.querySelectorAll`. Retorna todos elementos dentro de uma array com uma síntaxe para requisicionar elementos (ex: `'.class .wow label'`) usada em CSS (ou seja, interpretada), especificada no primeiro parâmetro. Este método pode ser indexado em um elemento, também. `Element.prototype.querySelectorAll`

O `document.getElementsByTagName` deve ter melhor suporte, então tente usar ele para obter todas `label` no seu HTML:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
```

Primeiro de tudo, não vai acontecer nada se modificar essa variável. Essa variável é uma array, porém ela tem seu protótipo (creio que seja `HTMLCollection`), também. Essa variável contém os elementos `label` que podem ser indexados por números e assim, modificados.

Para modificar todos os elementos `label` de uma vez, você terá que fazer uma execução repetida. Usar `for(expressão inicial; condição; ação)` é muito simples.

Aí, ao seu formulário ser validado ou invalidado, você pode fazer uma condição para gerar a string `"valido"` ou `"invalido"` e usar ela no atributo "class" de cada `label`. Se tiver uma outra classe inclusa, terá que adicionar ela junto.

```
var result = valida ? "valido" : "invalido",
    labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for(var i = 0, el; el = labels[i]; i ++) el.className = result;
```

Ou se preferir, adicione ou remova uma das classes como você queria fazer (melhor caso tiver diversas classes).

```
var addClass = valida ? "valido" : "invalido",
    removeClass = valida ? "invalido" : "valido",
    labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for(var i = 0, el; el = labels[i]; i ++) {
    el.removeClass(removeClass);
    el.className += " " + addClass;
}
```

Você faz isso depois de criar a variável `valida` no seu bloco.